# issue with permission for URL - first time writing an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It appears there is a problem with specifying the permission for the specific URL in Manifest V3, especially when dealing with query parameters. I can't get it to accept the url in any configuration.

here is my code. I am looking to build an extension to play an online streaming radio.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "NY Jewish Radio Player",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Play New York Jewish Radio",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "*://newyorkjewishradio.com/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

```
// content.js

// Function to interact with the play button
function interactWithPlayButton() {
  const playButton = document.querySelector("body > div.radio_player > div > div.radio-player-controls > button.radio-play-pause > svg > g > path");
  if (playButton) {
    playButton.click();
  }
}

interactWithPlayButton();
```

```
// popup.js

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");

  playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Find the active tab
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];

      // JavaScript code to interact with your player
      const codeToExecute = `
        // Find and click the play button on the website using the provided selector
        const playButton = document.querySelector("body > div.radio_player > div > div.radio-player-controls > button.radio-play-pause > svg > g > path");
        if (playButton) {
          playButton.click();
        }
      `;

      // Execute the code in the active tab
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTab.id, { code: codeToExecute }, function (result) {
        // Handle the result if needed
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
        } else {
          console.log("Script executed successfully.");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```
// background.js

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("newyorkjewishradio.com")) {
    // Inject the content script into the tab
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      function: interactWithPlayButton
    });
  }
});
```

I tried rewriting several times. With a tab option, with a popup html and without.

Comment: Move the site into a separate `"host_permissions"`. Also you seem to be using chatgpt because executeScript is used in two flavors (MV2 and MV3) and background.js lacks interactWithPlayButton.